# 2x Images retrieved from .xcassets sometimes give 1x instead

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a strange issue. The assets that I drop on the 2x square in the .xcassets are sometimes giving it in 1x instead. ie.If the asset is 100x100 in 2x, I am expecting an asset in 50x50 as it is dropped in the 2x pan, but instead the one that I am getting is the 1x version of the same. This is happening only when run on the device. When I am running it on the simulator, everything is working perfectly. I am using Xcode 6.1.1. Any ideas?

Comment: Be sure you're referencing your XCAssets exactly the way you named them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wont happen unless you accidentally place the 2x image in the 1x pan in the .xcasset. Make sure you place an image of 100x100 at your 2x and 50x50 at your 1x pans respectively.

This is a common mistake. Happened to me too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1697/_index.html

Case-sensitivity: iPhone OS uses a case-sensitive file system, unlike the Simulator which uses a case-insensitive file system by default. Make sure the case-sensitivity of resources accessed within code matches the filename case-sensitivity